# Meaning of reverse newlyweds?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

"The station doors open, and every officer in the building files down the stairs and forms a line on either side of me [Amy], holding the press back, creating an honor guard for me, and Rhonda and I run in holding hands like reverse newlyweds, rushing straight up to my parents who are waiting just inside the doorway"...

After you have married in church you usually rush out of the "doorway" to walk down the stairs of the church while your family and friends are cheering, hence the *reverse*? Am I way off?

Comment: I don't know about 'rush', but you come out of the church door to be met by a guard of honour, so, yes, I think you arer understanding it correctly.